# Adding additional classes to AngularJS Modal UI.Bootstrap modal

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog

I made a function to open modals and I'm having trouble trying to customize them.

According to the Documentation the windowClass parameter should add classes to the modal window, but its not working and I was wondering if any of you made it work

this is my code:

```
function openModal(title, msg) {

                $rootScope.modalTitle = title;
                $rootScope.modalmsg = msg;

                var notificationModal = $modal.open({
                    templateUrl : "app/modals/NewTicket.html",
                    controller  : function ($scope, $rootScope, $modalInstance) {

                        $scope.myTitle = $rootScope.modalTitle;
                        $scope.modalMsg = $rootScope.modalmsg;

                        $scope.cancel = function () {
                            $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
                        };
                    },
                    windowClass : "newTicket"     //THIS IS NOT WORKING
                });

            }
```

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in your console? From a quick scan of the source code your code appears to be correct.

Comment: nope, no errors, Im inspecting the modal element and the class is not being added

Comment: I played w/ the plunker for modals from here: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ and it adds the class I specified to the div with these classes (modal fade my-test-class in) "my-test-class" is the one I added. This is the parent of .modal-dialog and grandparent of .modal-content

Comment: Do you have [ui-bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) with templates?

Comment: can you share the plunker, i cant get it to work @Brocco

Comment: No problem: http://plnkr.co/edit/zoTL3gFnDg8IDFjyILYB?p=preview

Comment: Ok, I tried, and windowClass its adding the class to the backdrop, do you know what its the option for adding classes to the dialog??

Answer (score 7):

`ui-bootstrap` creates modal in following hierarchy

```
<div uib-modal-window="modal-window">
    <div class="modal-dialog ">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <!-- three more divs for header, body and footer-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The property `windowClass` adds css class to top most div (div with attribute `uib-modal-window`)

From your question it appears that, you want to apply your class to div with class `modal-content`

To achieve this you can do something like this

```
#add this class to windowClass 
.modal-window-extension {

}

#add your styling rules to this class
.modal-window-extension .modal-dialog .modal-content {
    opacity: 0.95;
    background-color: #2d2626;
}
```

Comment: tl;dr = The property windowClass adds css class to top most div

Answer (score 4):

```
var notificationModal = $modal.open({
                templateUrl : "app/modals/NewTicket.html",
                windowClass : "newTicket",
                controller  : function ($scope, $rootScope, $modalInstance) {

                    $scope.myTitle = $rootScope.modalTitle;
                    $scope.modalMsg = $rootScope.modalmsg;

                    $scope.cancel = function () {
                        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
                    };
                },
            });
```